# How to upload file to web service via Node and save the response as a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-request

I have been searching and testing various modules/methods in Node.js with the goal of being able to upload a file to my vendors API and save the response data (which is a .png file sent as binary data) to an image file. Most of the examples demonstrate how to upload a file to a Web directory, but not a Web service. Formidable (https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) is an example where it is easy to store in a Web directory, but I don't see how I can perform a simple post of form data to a Web service.

I have looked into using request (https://github.com/request/request) to post a file, but am confused as to what to put in their form example, specifically here:

```
// Pass a simple key-value pair
my_field: 'my_value',
```

My current attempt is using a mix of formidable and request, but it fails with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null

My HTML form is as follows:

```
<form action="/upload4" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Here is my Node/Formidable/Request Code:

```
app.post('/upload4', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        var options = {
            contentType: files.myfile.type,
            metadata: { fileName: files.myfile.name }
        };
        request.post({ url: 'http://myendpoint.net/uploadPDF', formData: form }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('upload failed:', err);
            }
            console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
            var options = { contentType: 'image/png' };
            blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, 'Reponse.png', body, options, function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            // Response from POST was uploaded to Azure as a PNG file
            res.send(result);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
        });
    console.log(req);
});
```

At this point, I would be happy with just being able to POST my file using Node with the end goal of being able to save the response (of a png file) to Azure.

Comment: Check out [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer?_ga=1.118185929.1795931354.1444833875). It's primary use is to upload files, and is maintained by the same people who maintain express.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Am I also not passing the data into note properly (should it be req.file instead of req.body.file)